# Visual Studio How to fade about unused using

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

```cs
using System.Windows.Input; // If unused 'using' fade.
using System.Text; // If unused 'using' fade.
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

I want to fade the unused Using.
What kind of settings should I set up in the visual studio?

---

Solution
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Fading -> Fade out unused usings

Comment: What do you mean by "detect"? If it's turning grey, then it's clearly being detected. Are you saying you actually want it automatically removed immediately? That would make it pretty hard to use, as you could never write a new using directive - it would immediately be unused. If you hit Ctrl-Shift-U, does that remove and reorder using directives for you? (It does for me, but I'm not sure whether that's just my settings...)

Comment: Is it not immediate for you? I don't seem to have this problem

Comment: This formatting is controlled by *Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Fading -> Fade out unused usings*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You could remove all at the same time and organize things by right click in the editor and press -> "Remove and Sort usings (CTRL+R, CTRL+G) (default I think). This works for the current file.
2. If you want to get a warning you could create a file in your solution named .editorconfig

[*.{cs,vb}]

IDE0005: Remove unnecessary imports dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0005.severity = warning"

---

Then set analysis setting to "Entire solution" like in the image below. Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Then the severity you could set to "suggestion", "warning" or "error" depending on what you want.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution to "fade out unused usings" not working in Visual Studio

Seeing *faded* or grayed out **using statements** has worked perfectly for a decade until **Visual Studio 2022**. It seems the designers didn't cross-correlate newer project settings with IDE settings, many of which now *conflict* in Visual Studio 2022. It might be expected that *project settings* override the *IDE settings*, but its still not intuitive.

SOLUTION

There are TWO SETTINGS you have to apply to enable this feature:

1. In Visual Studio 2022, go to `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced`. Scroll down to the "**Fading**" section then check "**fade out unused usings**"
2. In Visual Studio 2022, go to your **Project Properties** page by right-clicking your project and scrolling to the bottom and choosing `Properties`. You have to enable **Live Analysis** by going the `"Code Analysis"` section, then check `"Run on live analysis"`. Close this settings page to verify it saved and updated the cache. You can also manually fix this settings by opening up your `.csproj` file (or right-clicking your project and choosing `Edit Project File`) and simply verify this setting below was set when you checked the box above:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>True</RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>
<PropertyGroup>
```

After doing the above, open up any class or code page and see if any of your using statements are *greyed-out*. The issue here is the fact that the project settings in #2 override the Tools > Options settings in #1.

Comment: This seems to be even more broken in VS 17.8.3, and the above fix no longer seems to work.  Anybody have any ideas?